# How to check if df1 is equal to df2 in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark

```
df1.show()
+---------+
|Data_Type|
+---------+
|   string|
|   string|
|      int|
+---------+
df2.show()
+---------+
|Data_Type|
+---------+
|   string|
|   string|
|      int|
+---------+
```

I want to compare (equality check) the columns in df1 with the rows in df2["Column_name"].

I tried comparing them using joins i.e., by

```
df1.join(df2,on="Data_Type",how="left").join(df2,on="Data_Type",how="right")
if(df3.count() == df1.count() == df2.count()):
    print(True)
```

But this doesn't work since I have duplicate values under the column "Data_Type" and I am getting a cross product kind of an output after joining as below :

```
+---------+
|Data_Type|
+---------+
|      int|
|   string|
|   string|
|   string|
|   string|
|   string|
|   string|
|   string|
|   string|
+---------+
```

Any other way to do equality check on dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exceptAll`(preserves duplicates) (or) [`subtract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract) in spark.

```
df1.show()
#+---------+
#|Data_Type|
#+---------+
#|   string|
#|   string|
#|      int|
#+---------+


df2.show()
#+---------+
#|Data_Type|
#+---------+
#|   string|
#|   string|
#|      int|
#+---------+

df1.exceptAll(df2).count()
df2.exceptAll(df1).count()
#0
df1.subtract(df2).count()
df2.subtract(df1).count()
#0
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing well in these troubled times!

You can try subtraction of the two dataframes, after converting them into sets.
This way, you could convert the result into a dataframe.

```
    lst = []
    for row in set(df1.collect()) - set(df2.collect()):
         lst.append(row)
    spark.createDataFrame(lst)
```

Also, since we use sets, if you have more than one column, the order doesn't matter in both the dataframes.

Hope this helps!